# Handle multiple pages table in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, c#, selenium-webdriver

I have searched a lot to find a sample for handling tables in Selenium webdriver. All samples explain just for tables with just 5 or 10 rows. How can I handle tables like blow example:
https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues 
 How can I go through all pages of these kind of tables and get for example vlues of "Subject" column?
 Sample example for simple tables:
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/handle-dynamic-webtables-in-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Can you provide some more details as follows: 1. What is your objective? 2. What are you trying to do? 3. What have you tried still now?
 4. What worked for you? Show code. 5. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code may work. Here i'm getting all the issues subject and printing it in console, you can write any assert statement you required in inner for loop.

```
driver.get("https://www.redmine.org//projects//redmine//issues");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='per-page']/a[2]")).click();
    int num_of_clicks = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(
            By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/p[1]/a[3]")).getText());
    for (byte i = 1; i < num_of_clicks; i++) {
        List<WebElement> records_in_page = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='list issues']/tbody/tr"));
        for (byte j = 0; j < records_in_page.size(); j++) {
            String Issue_Subject = driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath(".//*[@class='list issues']/tbody/tr[" + (j+1)
                            + "]/td[5]")).getText();
            System.out.println(Issue_Subject);
        }
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='next']")).click();
    }
```

Comment: Just one problem, In the last page I have just 1 data, so program cannot find any element after that and I get exception. How can I handle this?

Comment: instead of 100 in second for loop keep the size of table for each page.

Comment: The size of tables is different in the last page

Comment: How can I store this output and sort it? Thank you for your help. I tried to store it in a text file but it stores only the last row not all of them.
`using (OutToFile redir = new OutToFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\names.txt"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(firstName);
                    }`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Krishna Reddy, this is for someone wants to use it in C#:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.redmine.org//projects//redmine//issues");
    driver.manage().window.maximize();
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='per-page']/a[2]")).click();
    int num_of_clicks = Int32.Parse(driver.FindElement(
            By.XPath(".//*[@id='content']/p[1]/a[3]")).Text);
    for (byte i = 1; i < num_of_clicks; i++) {
        IList<IWebElement> records_in_page = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@class='list issues']/tbody/tr"));
        for (byte j = 0; j < records_in_page.Count; j++) {
            String Issue_Subject = driver.FindElement(
                    By.XPath(".//*[@class='list issues']/tbody/tr[" + (j+1)
                            + "]/td[5]")).Text;
            Console.WriteLine(Issue_Subject);
        }
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='next']")).click();
    }
```